# Array keys validation (check that IDs exists in database)

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have to validate an array where the keys are IDs, like this:

```php
array:1 [
  "data" => array:3 [
    13 => array:1 [
      "price" => 100
    ]
    14 => array:1 [
      "price" => 200
    ]
    46 => array:1 [
      "price" => 300
    ]
  ]
]
```

So `13`, `14`, and `46` are IDs. I validate the `data` array and the `price` like this:

```php
$request->validate([
    'data' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
    'data.*.price' => ['required', 'numeric'],
]);
```

But I don't know how to validate the keys, saying something like `'data.*' => ['exists:table,id']`.

Is it possible?

Comment: This might help retrieving the inputs as a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input) you can access the keys

Comment: You can write you custom validation and get the key and the value in there. ($attribute, $vaue). [Refer to here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures)

Comment: You could convert the keys to another array and check if exists, easiest solution that came to my mind

Comment: `data.*` returns an array that have `price` key inside not the id. To access its id you will need to use foreach with [array_keys method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Then you can add new rule to validation array in each loop.

Comment: yes you can do exactly that https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name but just checking if the price exists might not be the best approach. it might be better for you to create a custom rule which would be able to check the price matches the record its claiming to be from